# OLE DB Exception - database/user/password is too large

Tags: oledb, oledbconnection, oledbexception

I'm trying to connect to a database using OleDbConnection and a connection string, the error given within the try-catch statement is 'database/user/password is too large'. What does that statement mean, and how can I solve this problem so I can connect to my database? My database is using a SQLBase driver.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string probably can have a database, user, and/or password in it. One or more of them is too large.

Answer (score 0):

SQLBase has restrictions on the length of the database, user, and password parameters. The database name has a maximum of 16 characters, and the user and password fields have a maximum length of 8 characters.